# DotNetNuke (dnn) login problems in IE7

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

I justed moved out dnn website to a new webserver running Windows 2008 64-bit.  After some tweaks I was able to get things running great.  However there is one last quirk.  When I try to login to the admin/host portion of the site, I receive an error.  Specifically, I get

```
A critical error has occurred.- Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I only get this error when logging in with Internet Explorer 7, ironically.  I can login successfully using FF3.  Does anyone have any idea what would cause this?  I'm at a total loss.

I'm running dnn 3.0.13 in IIS7 using Classic application pool.

**There are no errors/exceptions reported in the Log in the dnn application or en the Event Viewer on the web server.  Frustrating, I know.**

Andrew

Comment: What version of DotNetNuke are you running? What (if any) third party modules do you have installed? Do you have any custom authentication / login modules? Where exactly does this error appear in the login workflow? What type of error is it (e.g. red dnn triangle or yellow screen of death)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why are you running such an old version of dnn?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, there were more problems than just IE7 login issues.  Whenever I tried to update content, I would receive errors (red triangle, but nothing in the logs).  In the end, I realized that my very old DNN version was not capable of running in .NET 2.0.  I'm running such an old version because it's a legacy application that I still need to support.  Clearly, an upgrade path should be explored.

Anyways, my solution was to install .NET 1.1.  I followed the instructions listed [here](http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/03/20/iis7-running-asp-net-1-1-applications.aspx).  I didn't have this problem on my other web servers because they come with .NET 1.1 pre-installed.  IIS7 doesn't come bundled with it.

This fixed all of my problems and it ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look in the application event log of your server, and if you see the exception, edit your question and post it?